# Problems with DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment that shows two seekbar and three buttons. This dialog fragment needs to call a method (call it `getSomeData()`) of its activity to setup its view, so i call it in `onCreateView()`. `getSomeData()` needs to access to data that is initialized in the `onCreate()` method of the activity. The question is: does the `onCreateView()` method of the dialog fragment gets called after the `onCreate()` method of the activity? How should i handle this type of situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this info on fragment lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

If you need to do something after the activity is created `onActivityCreated()` is where you want to put it.